# Does the limit exits if $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{n}$ if $b_n$ is monotone increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose that $b_n$ is monotone increasing in $n$.

Question: Does the following limit exits (in the extended sense)?
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{b_n}{n}
\end{align}

If not, I would like to see an example that shows that $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are different?

Comment: Take $b_n=n^2$, then it is monotone increasing but the limit does not exist

Comment: @Loobear23  No, the limit exists. It is given by infinity.

Comment: @Lisa I think you should clarify in the question that you also allow divergence to $\infty$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I have added a note.

Comment: I don’t think it has to exist: For example $b_n$ could make many small jumps and then a big jump every once in a while so $b_n/n$ could oscillate between $1$ and $2$ for example

Comment: Consider $b_n = 2^{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}$ (you can add $\sqrt{n}$ to it if you want it to be strictly increasing)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you.